# ¿Por qué no me guarda los datos esta consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Hago una consulta desde la capa modelo hacia mysql pero no me guarda los datos.

¿Me pueden ayudar?

```
function editar($id_usuario,$telefono,$residencia,$correo,$sexo,$adicional){
        $sql="UPDATE usuario SET telefono_us=:telefono,residencia_us=:residencia,correo_us=:correo,sexo_us=:sexo,adicional_us=:adicional WHERE id_usuario=:id";
        $query = $this->acceso->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':id'=>$id_usuario,':telefono'=>$telefono,':residencia'=>$residencia,':correo'=>$correo,':sexo'=>$sexo,':adicional'=>$adicional));
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y quien llama a esa funcion? y de que forma?

Comment: El código del `UPDATE` no parece erróneo desde el punto de vista sintáctico. Pero tu pregunta es incompleta. ¿Qué verificaste, tienes errores, cuáles, qué esperas obtener, qué obtienes? Deberías establecer controles en el código, como verificar si la consulta tuvo éxito, y devolver quizá mensajes de error o de éxito. Lo que si veo mal escrito son las llamadas a `fetchAll`, tienes escrito `all` con a minúscula, si usas PDO es con `A` por lo que creo que tu código no funciona quizá debido a errores en otra parte.